# UICollectionView's performBatchUpdates crash iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, batch-updates

I noticed a strange difference in how `performBatchUpdates:completion:` method of `UICollectionView` works in iOS7 (bad - crashes) and iOS8 (good). Here's the code I use:

```
[self.swapItems removeObject:self.swapItems[indexPath.row]];

[self.swapItemsGrid performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.swapItemsGrid deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self layoutViews];
}];
```

In iOS8 it works fine, while in iOS7 it crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

A little debugging has shown that in iOS8 the `performBatchUpdates:completion:` method calls the data source method `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`, while in iOS7 it doesn't, hence the error where a cell is attempted to be created with the data of an object that is in the data array no more.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Perhaps you have a solution in mind?

Comment: Oh, it's worth noting that it only happens if I remove an item (executes code above - no crash), add an item, remove an item again (executes code above - CRASH). In both cases though the `self.swapItems` array is the same.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

`self.swapItemsGrid` might does not have item at index `indexPath`.
To avoid this, use this to check `indexPath` exits in array or not:

```
-(BOOL)checkIndexPathExits:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath inArray:(NSArray*)array{
    if (indexPath.section < array.count) {
        if (indexPath.row < [array[indexPath.section] count]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid it's not that easy. The only place I can do this kind of check is in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, and if the method gets called at all, I have to return an instance of `UICollectionViewCell`. That's why there's the `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` method to ensure that the data array has sufficient objects for each requested `indexPath`.